# String contains any but one character

Tags: java, string, contains, metacharacters

I want to check if a String contains a `}` with any character in front of it except `\`.
As far as I know I can use `.` as a metacharacter in `aString.contains(...)` to allow any character at that position but I don’t know how to create something like a blacklist: `aString.contains(“.(except ‘\‘)}“`Is that possible without creating an own method?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I‘ve tried aString.contains(“[^\\]}“)

Comment: `String.contains()` only works with plain text, it doesn't work with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need regex (well technically you don't *need* regex, but it's the best way):

```
if (aString.matches(".*(?<!\\\\)}.*"))
```

This [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) says the string should be made up as follows

- `.*` zero or more of any character
- `(?<!\\\\)` the previous char is not a backslash
- `}` a curly right bracket
- `.*` zero or more of any character

This also works for the edge case of the first char being the curly bracket.

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/vpETxrAyNunRFU).

Comment: "it's the best way" for one definition of best. Most concise, yes. Most readable.... probably not.

Comment: @Andy although regex is hard to read, it's readable if you are familiar and it's the goto approach for basic (ie non-AST style) "parsing". I would frown on anyone throwing their own code at this kind of problem when regex is a good fit (as here), so you can move on and do something else.